# Direct Carrier Billing - Is it worth Implementing

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, billing, payment-processing

I have a Mobile website which sell Products, its built in Asp.net/C#. I am exploring the idea of adding a new Payment Method on my website which will allow customers to pay using their Carrier aka Direct Carrier billing.

I want to get opinion from folks who have Direct Carrier Billing implemented on their Mobile Website.

- How well was it received by the Customers
- How complex is it to implement such a payment method (is it worth implementing)
- Lastly, has anyone implemented http://www.billtomobile.com/, are there any other options apart from billtomobile

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience developing wap premium billing in some countries (es, it, za, pt, etc), normally using big aggregators. Usually it´s very simple to develop. There are http APIs, and you have to redirect consumer to carrier billing page, and it returns to you with billing information. Normally consumer has to accept the payment in carrier payment page.

I think main problem it´s you only can bill in some APNs for example, you can´t bill to blackberries or opera mini consumers, so other APNs don´t support wap payments. For example, in spain there is a commercial APN called "internet connection". Of course, you can´t bill to wifi users.

I think in others countries like UK, wap payments are broadly accepted. I belive one option is to mix wap payment with SMS premium.